# Unable to install npm package bycrpt locally

Tags: node.js, npm

Hi I have recently started to work with npm packages in nodejs. While installing an npm package named bycrypt I am getting the following error

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0<br/>
npm ERR! argv "node" /usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "bycrypt"<br/>
npm ERR! node v0.12.4<br/>
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.2<br/>
npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED<br/>
```

I am able to install the bycrypt package globally and in other folders but not in the same folder where this error is occuring. I am unable to understand what this error is and what is its workaround.

Also my registry setting is registry = https://registry.npmjs.org/ and still the issue persists. Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Check if in folder where launch npm there a file .npmrc

Comment: I checked and there is a file .npmrc